# Updating Custom Config Section

Tags: .net, app-config

I have a config Section in my app.config that looks like this

```
<configSections>
    <section name="importSettingsSection" type="MyApp.Console.Config.ImportSettingsSection, MyApp.Console"/>
</configSections>
<importSettingsSection>
    <serviceSettings pollInterval="50" runAt="1400" />
    <systems>
        <add name="System1" lastRunDate="12/01/2010" />
        <add name="System2" lastRunDate="12/01/2010" />
    </systems>
</importSettingsSection>
```

I was wondering if anyone could help me figure out how to modify the lastRunDate under the systems node at runtime.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, you won't have write access to this file.  An app.config file is not a database, write it somewhere else.  A file, a database, whatever you like.